# Official definition of 'noncompeting'

Tags: discussion, answers, noncompeting

Recently, I was looking at one of my older questions, [QWERTY Quine Creation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78728/qwerty-quine-creation), and I noticed that the JavaScript answer was invalid. I notified the creator, who marked the answer noncompeting. The same thing happened on [another question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80073/how-to-find-the-item-in-a-list-whose-fitem-is-the-smallest) (not mine), but the answer was deleted. Hence my question: **Is non-competing going to far?** I think we need an official definition of 'non-competing'. I think that the current definition (any answer which breaks the rules) does not work. What is your opinion?

Comment: [Closely related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7987/42963)

Comment: I think the linked question is pretty clear that breaking the rules is not an option, regardless of whether you say so or not in the answer. "Noncompeting" should be used exclusively for languages/versions which are newer than the challenge but otherwise comply with all of the rules.

Comment: I don't believe the current definition you give is correct. I think "non-competing" status is given only to answers that break specific rules that only exist to prevent boring loopholes (e.g. the language being newer than the challenge), answers that don't meet the spec of the question should be handled according to the consensus from the linked post.

Comment: The linked question answers this question - this is a dupe.